# Thread exercise - Help me understand

Tags: java, multithreading

Well, I am a student in the second semester, and now we are going trough threads. I mostly get it, but something is off about one of my exercises and I can't quite understand it.

"In a bakery shop, you often have to take a number when you arrive at the shop and then wait until it is your
turn (with the right number)."
Im going to copy-paste the methods in the monitor where I think the problem might be.

```
private NumberDispenser(){
    nextNoToTake=1;
    nextNoToServe=0;
}

public static NumberDispenser accessDispenser(){
    if(theOne == null){
        theOne = new NumberDispenser();
    }
    return theOne;
}


@Override
public synchronized void takeNextNumber() {
    int currNo = nextNoToTake;
    nextNoToTake++;
    notifyAll();
    System.out.println("No:"+currNo+" has been taken|nextNoToServe:"+nextNoToServe);
    while(currNo != nextNoToServe)
        {try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    System.out.println("No:"+currNo+" has been served");
    notify();
}

@Override
public synchronized int nextCustomer() {//Serves the current customer and goes to the next one
    System.out.println("Clerk is ready to deal with a new customer");

    while((nextNoToServe)>=nextNoToTake-1)
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    nextNoToServe++;
    notifyAll();
    System.out.println("Now serving No:"+(nextNoToServe));

    return nextNoToServe;
}
```

This is the monitor class. There are two more , for the Customer and for the Clerk , and one more for testing. The customer class has Thread.sleep to simulate time for browsing then goes into dispenser.takeNextNumber();, after which it should finish and the thread responsible for it should die by itself(in the main class).Clerk loops dispenser.nextCustomer() endlessly with a delay.The main method creates , in separate for loops, a number of customers and their threads , and a number of clerks and their threads.

///// This is copy pasted from the requirements.
Customer arrivals and clerk servings are simulated by threads.

Implement as a monitor a class NumberDispencer that implements the interface TakeANumber.
Hint: you could define the two instance variables
 private int nextNumberToTake = 1;
 private int nextNumberToServe = 1;

Implement two thread classes:
 A thread class which simulates customer taking a number and being served
 A thread class that simulates clerk serving, that is getting the next customer number and then make
service.

Implement a class with a main method to simulate a bakery shop with e.g. two serving clerks and ten
customers.
/////

I have almost fixed the code. The problem was in the condition of the while loops. Now it works almost as intended, but it skips over the first customer. Only the first customer is skipped, then it all goes how it should.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPgME.png)

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of this program, and what is the behaviour you're experiencing? Judging by the code, deadlocks are a possibility.

Comment: You question is still not clear. Do you want to understand the above code. Or you want to you this code in your exercise.

Comment: Whatever your problem maybe, but takeNextNumber() never calls notify() or notifyAll() ? Have you ever considered why?? because by calling wait() you are basically signaling other threads to hang for a certain period, and those **waits** never deserved a notify() or notifyAll()?

Comment: I've added some more explanation. The customer threads never reach their ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one place where it is broken.

**Hint:**  Suppose that there is one server and one customer, and the server calls `nextCustomer()` before a customer arrives.  What will wake it up when the customer arrives?

Also, this statement is a hack.

```
if (nextNoToServe == 0)
    nextNoToServe = 1;
```

That should be dealt with by initializing the instance variables to appropriate values; e.g. in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, trying to understand it a bit better.
I have put a single clerk and a single customer. The order they do things is messed up too. I have removed all the thread sleeps to 'simulate' them working, and will try to find whats wrong with the wait and notify parts

Comment: I see, when the clerks are ready to deal with the customers , before any come (naturally) the customers come and get served instantly. So is the placement of the counters wrong, or is it doing what it's supposed to, I just messed up with the placement of Sysouts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have seen and corrected one error, but now it just skips over the first customer. I'll keep looking, but you have been very helpful, thanks :)

Comment: You are approaching this the wrong way.  It is not about fiddling with the statements to get them to give you the expected output.  It is really about thinking (deeply) about all of the scenarios, and **designing** the code to behave correctly.  Indeed, I would say that you need to develop an informal proof (for yourself) that you have covered all of the scenarios correctly.